# DIAL Launch parameters for Chromecast receiver app

Tags: google-cast

I am able to launch Chromecast app via standard DIAL. However, the launch parameters (either query string or POST data) do not reach the receiver app.

Does anyone how to get launcher parameters to a Chromecast receiver app without using Google Cast API on the sender side?

Some context: trying to do a Chromecast sender app without using Google Cast API.

Thanks

Alex

Comment: I suggest having a look at Fling on Github.  It's a Java app that doesn't use the Google Cast API.  https://github.com/entertailion/Fling.  Be aware, of course, that by not using the Google Cast SDK functionality may break in the future.

Comment: This helps to understand the framework better. However, the code did not work as is. I think Google may have changed. This also did not include the Java source for the lower level modules like web socket. Had to use packet sniffer and hex calculator to figure out. (The target implementation is not in Java.) But I would say looking at Fling gave this effort a jump start. Thanks.