# How to launch a Chromecast app using DIAL

Tags: chromecast

I am trying to understand how to launch a registered Chromecast application using DIAL. Alex mentioned he has done this (hopefully he reads this post): [DIAL Launch parameters for Chromecast receiver app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20577221/dial-launch-parameters-for-chromecast-receiver-app)
I know this likely won't fly in production, but I would like to see if it can be done on a prototype basis. I am guessing I will need to do a POST to x.x.x.x:8008/apps/Chromecast and somehow add the AppID as post data. But I have not been successful.

Answer (score 0):

Using DIAL, you won't be able to launch an app which is registered through the developer portal.